# How can I refresh a datatable inside a div using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Here is my code:

```
oTable2 = $('#BigData2').dataTable({
    "bLengthChange":false,
    "bPaginate":false,
    "oLanguage": {
        "sZeroRecords": "No records found"
    },
    "sAjaxSource":'StatusSrv',
    // "sDom":'RCT<"clear">lfrtip',
    //"aoColumnDefs":[{}]
})
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function (){
        $('#Status_Table').fadeOut('slow').load('SupplyPlanning.jsp 
            #oTable2.fnDraw()').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 6000);

<div id="Status_Table" class="chartFloatLeftInner">
    <table id="BigData2" >
        <thead >
            <tr>
                <th><input type="checkbox" onClick="checkall()" name="maincheck" id="maincheck"/></th>
                <th  title="REQ_NO">REQ_NO</th>
                <th  title="Retailer Partner number">Retailer num</th>
                <th title="STATUS">OVERALL_STATUS</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
```

I want to refresh my datatable in a particular time interval so that I am using `fndraw`  but it only redraws the table with the old data.  If I insert new data in the database, the new data is not shown after refresh; it shows only the old data.

Comment: how is this related with `Java`? and if I was in a bad mood, I will downvote this because of your ugly formatting

Comment: I think there's a tag that's missing here.  Do you mean the datatable jquery plugin?

Comment: If it redraws it but with old data the issue is probably on your server side? I guess `SupplyPlanning.jsp` in your case?

Comment: There's no concept of data binding in dataTable, it literally accepts your data, creates an independent object from it and draws the table and forgets that anything else exists.  It keeps no connection to the data object that you sent to build the table initially.  If you want it to redraw based on new data, it does allow you to change row data as required, which is tedious, or you can clear the table and rebuild it and redraw it.  It seems like an odd choice but when some of us are dealing with twenty five thousand rows, it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you would need to add the `"bDestroy": true` attribute to your datatable code which allow you to rebuild it otherwise once created you can not load it with new data.

Answer (score 0):

Try using append:

```
$('#Status_Table').append( your table in here);
```

It work for me